# KnockoutJS: How to add one observableArray to another?

Tags: javascript, binding, knockout.js, html-select, ko.observablearray

I want to add selected options from select element to binding table. The view model has addItem function that add selectedItems array into addedItems array with using ko.utils.arrayPushAll(). But nothing happens when I click on Add button (calls addItem function). How to correctly add one observable array to another?

**HTML**

```
<label>Parameter list</label>
<br/>
<select multiple="multiple" 
        data-bind="options: items, selectedOptions: selectedItems, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id'">
</select>
<p>
    <button data-bind="click: addItem, enable: selectedItems().length > 0">Add</button>
</p>

<label>Selected parameters</label>
<br/>
<table data-bind="visible: addedItems().length > 0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th />
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: addedItems">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: id"/>
                <span data-bind="text: name" /> 
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: value" /></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeItem">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
​var dataSource = [
    new Parameter({ id: "1", name: "param1", value: "" }),
    new Parameter({ id: "2", name: "param2", value: "" }),
    new Parameter({ id: "3", name: "param3", value: "" })
    ];

function Parameter(data) {
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.value = ko.observable(data.value);
}

function ParameterSelectList() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(dataSource);
    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.addedItems = ko.observableArray([]);

    // Operations
    self.addItem = function() {
        ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.addedItems, self.selectedItems);
        self.items.removeAll(self.selectedItems);
    };
    self.removeItem = function(item) {
        self.items.push(item);
        self.addedItems.remove(item);
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ParameterSelectList());​
```

Live example - http://jsfiddle.net/6H2PK/7/

***UPDATED***: Working example with removing selected items - http://jsfiddle.net/ebash/xxNak/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things going on here:

1) You are using the 'optionsValue' binding, so selectedItems is just going to contain a list of ids

2) arrayPushAll works with "native" arrays, not observableArrays.  You can still make this work by using the self.addedItems() and self.selectedItems() forms, but you will then need to call self.addedItems.valueHasMutated() to let subscribers know of the changes.

3) removeAll takes in a "native" array parameter, not an observableArray.

Here is a final fiddle that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/6H2PK/8/

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have one question: why is "removeAll" function "native"? self.items.removeAll(self.selectedItems()); deletes items from <select> element, isn't it?

Comment: What I meant by "native" is that it expects a standard JavaScript array (not an observableArray - which is, like all observables, a function).  For each element in the passed in array, it will remove the same item (if present) from the self.items observableArray.  The observableArray notifies all subscribers that it has changed, and that causes the select element to re-render.

Comment: removeAll isn't "native" function - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Comment: Yes, I know it's a Knockout function. I'm not talking about the function... I'm talking about the the parameter you pass into it.  You cannot say: observableArray1.removeAll(observableArray2).  You have to say: observableArray1.removeAll(observableArray2()) - returning the underlying "native" JavaScript array.