# knockout checkbox binding selected value

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js

I am learning knockout and was trying to build a page that will build a list of selectable users.
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Just/XtzJk/3/ (I am unable to get the data assignment right).

The data assignment is working in my page as I make a call to Controller, like below and it binds to the controls as expected

```
$.getJSON("/Wizard/GetUsers",function(allData){
        var mappedUsers = $.map(allData.AllUsers, function(item){return new User(item)});
        self.AllUsers(mappedUsers);
        if(allData.SelectedUsers != null){
        var mappedSelectedUsers = $.map(allData.SelectedUsers, function(item){return new User(item)});
        self.SelectedUsers(mappedSelectedUsers);}
    });
```

Problems:

<strike>a.) What's wrong with the JSFiddle I wrote?</strike>  Got it working.

<strike>b.) In my code I am able to get the function for selected checkbox invoked but I am unable to get the value stored in the "User" parameter that I receive in the function. In Chrome JS console I can see the user object has the right value stored, I just am unable to retrieve it.</strike> Got this by doing ko.toJS().

Thanks.

EDIT:
Ok, I got my JSFiddle working, I had to select Knockout.js in the framework. The updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Just/XtzJk/5/

Also, for getting the selected checkboxe's value I did

```
ko.toJS(user).userName
```

But I think I'll take the approach of selecting values from a list and then on click move them to another "Selected" list and remove the values from the previous ones. Got this idea from this post: [KnockoutJS: How to add one observableArray to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758490/knockoutjs-how-to-add-one-observablearray-to-another)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I think I've got the solution you need...

I started by setting up an observable array of `selectedUserNames`, and I applied this to the `<li>` elements like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       name="checkedUser" 
       data-bind="value: userName, checked:$root.selectedUserNames" />
```

[Note: it's important to declare the `value` before declaring the `checked` binding, which threw me for a bit… ya learn something new every day!]

Why bind an array of userName values to the checked binding?  Well, when an array is passed to the `checked` binding, KO will compare the value of each checkbox to the values in the `checked` array and check any checkbox where its value is in that array.  (Probably explained better in the [KO documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html))

Then, while I left the observableArray for SelectedUsers, I set up a manual subscription to populate it, like so:

```
self.selectedUserNames.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    var newSelectedUserNames = newValue;
    var newSelectedUsers = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(newSelectedUserNames, function(userName) {
        var selectedUser = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.AllUsers(), function(user) {
            return (user.userName() === userName);
        });
        newSelectedUsers.push(selectedUser);
    });
    self.SelectedUsers(newSelectedUsers);
});
```

[I had originally tried to set up a dependent observable (ko.computed) for selectedUserNames with functions for both read and write, but the checkbox wasn't having it.]

This subscription function examines the new `selectedUserNames` array, looks up the user from `AllUsers` whose `userName` matches a value in that `selectedUserNames` array, and pushes matching `User` objects to the `SelectedUsers` array… well, actually it pushes each matching `User` to a temp array and then that temp array is assigned to `SelectedUsers`, but the goal is met.  The `SelectedUsers` array will now always contain what we want it to contain.

Oh, I almost forgot… here's the fiddle I created, so you've got the full solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jimmym715/G2hxP/

Hope this helps, but let me know if you have any questions

Comment: As I updated my question (prior to seeing your post), I ended up using something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Just/5gxvd/
However, your fiddle looks more complex and I'll study it to understand what it does. And maybe post more questions as comments if I do not understand anything. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The order of `value:` and `checked:` doesn't matter (the order of application of each binding within a binding collection is not deterministic) - but they must both be specified for this behavior.